# How can I make sure that app developed in xcode4.2 will support ios4 as well as ios5

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, ios4, ios-simulator

I am using xcode4.2 , I want my app to support ios4 and ios5 as well,can someone guide me how can i make sure that my app will support both and how can I test my app in simulator(for ios4 and ios5)

Comment: Run Your app in both version of simulators(4 and 5.0) and find any issues is there.that will help you to make sure yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your target's summary view (select project icon at top of Navigator view, elect your target in the editor view, select the Summary tab), set the "Deployment Target" to 4.0, then make your code such that you either don't use any API newer than 4.0 or you conditionally use it based on the installed OS version.

Answer (score 1):

ABSOLUTELY NO SIMULATOR.  The simulator is WIDLY different from a real iOS device.  I recommend buying something cheap off of EBay and loading iOS 4.x into it if you really want to do some serious issue finding.  Speaking from experience, we released a buggy version that was just meant to be a minor bug fix (ARC+Leaves= Epic Fail), anyways, because we did not test on a physical device, we shipped a build that crashed on startup.  You NEED to test compatibility on a physical device.

Comment: I am testing my app in iphone4 which has ios5. The only thing i am worried about is how can I ensure that my app will work fine in ios4 as well,any idea?

Comment: If you are really worried, buy a cheap device on eBay and load it with iOS 4.  That's the only real guarantee.